# Pivot data in SQL (repeated levels)

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a question regarding pivoting data in SQL.

Input data: 
TABLE NAME temp

```
id cat  value
1   A     22
1   B     33
1   C     44
1   C     55
```

My ideal output would be:

```
id  A   B   C
1   22  33  44
1   22  33  55
```

Can someone provide some hints on this?
Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: What's the expected result if (1, D, 66) is inserted into the table? Another column (D) in the result?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hey, why did you ruin the formatting? Put one empty row before the block of sample data, and 4 blanks first in each row with sample data.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from
(
  select
  id,cat,value 
  from tablename
)
as tablo
pivot
(
sum(value)
for cat in ([A],[B],[C])
) as p
order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when, assuming  you did a mistake in output format in 2nd rows

```
select id, max( case when cat='A' then value end) as A,
   max(case when cat='B' then value end) as B,
max(case when cat='C' then value end)as C from table
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE WHEN and MAX aggregation:

```
   select id, max(case when cat='A' then value end) as A,max(case when cat='B' then value end) as B,
    max(case when cat='C' then value end) as C from temp
    group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `row_number()` function with conditional aggregation :

```
select id, max(case when cat = 'a' then value end) a,
           max(case when cat = 'b' then value end) b,
           max(case when cat = 'c' then value end) c
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id, cat order by value) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by id, seq;
```

However, it doesn't produce your actual output (it leaves null value where the cat has only one value compare to other cats) but it will give the idea of how to do that.